# Array sorting problem - Codewars Kata "Organize a Round-robin tournament"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am attempting to do this Kata - https://www.codewars.com/kata/organize-a-round-robin-tournament/train/javascript.

The task is to create a function that organizes a round robin tournament.

Example:

```
buildMatchesTable(4)
```

Should return a matrix like:

```
[
  [[1,2], [3, 4]],  // first round:  1 vs 2, 3 vs 4
  [[1,3], [2, 4]],  // second round: 1 vs 3, 2 vs 4
  [[1,4], [2, 3]]   // third round:  1 vs 4, 2 vs 3
]
```

So far I have listed all possible matchups, but my code to put them in the correct format is incorrect, throwing the error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

I would greatly appreciate all responses as dumbed down as possible as I am new to this. Thanks a mil.

```js
function buildMatchesTable(numberOfTeams) {
  let pairs = [];
  let n = numberOfTeams;
  let arr = [];
  //create all possible pairs without repeating
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    for (var j = i+1; j <= n; j++){
      pairs.push([i,j]);  
    }
  }

//not working
for (var i = 0; i < (n-1); i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < pairs.length; j++){
      for (var k = 0; k < 2; k++){
        if (!arr[i][j][k].includes(pairs[j][0]) && !arr[i][j][k].includes(pairs[j][1])){
        arr[i][j].push(pairs[j]);
        pairs.splice(j,1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

buildMatchesTable(6)
```

Comment: If you click "Run code snippet", it tells you: `TypeError: arr[i] is undefined`. So now you know that JS tells you `arr[i]` does not exist. It's undefined. If you look at your code, you are telling JS that `arr` is an array. But you are not doing anything with it. You never push any values to that array, yet you are trying to access them: `arr[i][j][k]`. You cannot check if something includes something if it doesn't exist.

Comment: The same goes for this part btw `arr[i][j].push(pairs[j])`. Even if you were to pass the if statement, the same issue would arise here because you can't push something to something that doesn't exist either.

Comment: Thank you. Any tips on how I should approach this problem another way? Just need a bit of direction and I can try figure it out from there

Comment: I don't have the time right now to come up with a solution for this challenge. But if you want to build upon what you already have, check if it exists or not: `if(arr[i] !== null)`. If that returns false, you know the array is still empty. You also know that the first iteration of your loop variables will all be 0. So you could just push an empty array to `arr` and then another to `arr[0]` etc. Then push `pairs[j]` manually and allow your existing loops to continue.